# Check if a word from one text file is in a second text file (C++)

Tags: c++

I've got two text files: The first has ~100,000 words and the other has ~850,000 words. Both have been parsed into separate Vectors. If a word is in both files, I need to do something.

I've written some C++ code that loops through the first and the second file, but the time complexity is O(n^2) which with files this big is taking forever to run through. Even after 15 minutes it doesn't seem close to being finished.

```
for (string word1 : firstTextFile)
            {
                for (string word2 : secondTextFile)
                {
                    if (word1 == word2)
                    {
                        doSomething();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Is there a faster way to do this? I've searched everywhere but I've got no idea what to do. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Use the swiss army knife of algorithm design: Sort the data!

Comment: Both vectors have been sorted alphabetically with all duplicate words removed, it's still really slow!

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong: Linear search on a sorted vector. Anyhow, consider the first two elements: Either they are the same, or you can discard the lower one, because it can't possibly be matched. Also, there are other containers that offer faster lookup without additional programming on your side.

Comment: If you don't care about the order of the words, then you can use `std::unordered_set` which has a find() method of complexity O(1).

Comment: *Both vectors have been sorted alphabetically with all duplicate words removed* -- You must add this important information into you question!

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: yes.

The `std::set_intersection` function handles this case in linear time. If you are able to, simply use that.

([reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/))

Comment: But you need to sort both of the vectors, then +O(nlogn)

Comment: Please add explicitely that it's a solution for sorted vectors.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <algorithm>

for (string word1 : firstTextFile) {
  if (std::binary_search(secondTextFile.begin(), secondTextFile.end(), word1) {
    doSomething();
  }
}
```

Complexity above is *O(firstTextFile.size() * log(secondTextFile.size())*.

If you would use `std::unoredered_set<std::string> secondTextFile` instead of `std::vector<std::string> secondTextFile`:

```
for (string word1 : firstTextFile) {
  if (secondTextFile.count(word1)) {
    doSomething();
  }
}
```

Complexity is *O(firstTextFile.size())*.

Additionally you would save time on inserting and sorting words into `secondTextFile`: *O(secondTextFile.size())* instead of *O(secondTextFile.size() * log(secondTextFile.size()))*.

Answer (score 1):

As both vectors have been sorted, then the algorithm to achieve this is akin to a merge sort.

There is a linear walk through the lists, with the algorithm trying to keep both lists at about the same part of the dictionary ordering.

```
while( worda && wordb ){
    if( worda == wordb ){
       DoSomething();
       worda = nextWordFromA();
       wordb = nextWordFromB();
    } else if ( worda < wordb ) {
       worda = nextWordFromA();
    } else {
       wordb = nextWordFromB();
    }
}
```